# Splitting a dataframe column row-wise with boolean conditions into multiple columns with fixed headers in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I downloaded a dataset from this website https://aps.dac.gov.in/APY/Public_Report1.aspx One has to make selections and on the basis of my selection, I got a file that contained data for the year 2017-2018 for all the states and all the crops. This is how the dataset looks like after importing using `read_excel()`

```
State/Crop/District             Season  Area (Hectare)  Production (Tonnes) Yield (Tonnes/Hectare)
0   Andaman and Nicobar Islands NaN             NaN     NaN                 NaN
1   Arecanut                    NaN             NaN     NaN                 NaN
2   1.NICOBARS                  Rabi            534.10  125.23              0.234469
3   2.NORTH AND MIDDLE ANDAMAN  Rabi            1744.00 4639.44             2.66023
4   3.SOUTH ANDAMANS            Rabi            1220.20 10518.7             8.62047
6   Arhar/Tur                   NaN             NaN     NaN                 NaN
7   1.NORTH AND MIDDLE ANDAMAN  Rabi            1.20    0.6                 0.5
9   Black pepper                NaN             NaN     NaN                 NaN
10  1.NICOBARS                  Rabi            12.40   0.42                0.033871
11  2.NORTH AND MIDDLE ANDAMAN  Rabi            8.76    2.13                0.243151
12  3.SOUTH ANDAMANS            Rabi            69.46   349.72              5.03484
```

The first column which is named `State/Crop/District` contains three different values which according to me should have been in three different columns but are not. What's also interesting is that not all the crops are grown in all the districts. My goal is to have it in the following way.

```
State                       Crop     District                 Season    Area    Production    Yield
Andaman and Nicobar Islands Arecanut Nicobars                 Rabi      534     125.23        0.2344
Andaman and Nicobar Islands Arecanut North and Middle Andaman Rabi      1744    4639.44       2.66023
```

and so on. There are around 27 states like Andaman and Nicobar Islands and around 54 distinct crops and numerous districts. I tried three ways to solve this problem, but couldn't get success in any of them.

1. I used `pivot` function in pandas but it made a dataframe containing around 12000 columns. That's not what I want.
2. I used `melt` on the first column and `values_vars` for others. The result was similar to the first run.
3. I created a custom function that scans for the row which contains the word `Total`. This is where two crops are separated in the raw file I downloaded, but I couldn't scale it to the other states.

Some of the answers recommend using `stack()` and `unstack()` but I am not able to see how can that be used here because I don't see multiple indices. I am a newbie to Pandas and using Python 3. Help would be appreicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing flow:.

1. Split the data frame by NA
2. Extend the data frame as a header from the index
3. Fill the NA with the column name of `method='ffill'` in the extended column.
4. Combine the header data frame and the split data frame
5. Modify the column names and add the 'state' column
6. Delete the first character of the 'District' column

There may be room for improvement, but the following code will do.

```
tmp = df[df['Season'].isnull()]
tmp2 = df[~df['Season'].isnull()]
new_index = np.arange(0, df.index.max()+1)
header1 = tmp.reindex(new_index)
header1 = header1['State/Crop/District'].fillna(method='ffill')
final = pd.concat([header1, tmp2], axis=1)
final.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
final['State'] = df['State/Crop/District'][0]
final.columns = ['Crop', 'District', 'Season','Area (Hectare)', 'Production (Tonnes)', 'Yield (Tonnes/Hectare)','State']
final = final[['State','Crop', 'District', 'Season','Area (Hectare)', 'Production (Tonnes)', 'Yield (Tonnes/Hectare)']]
final['District'] = final['District'].str.replace(r'^\d\.','')

final
|    | State                       | Crop         | District                 | Season   |   Area (Hectare) |   Production (Tonnes) |   Yield (Tonnes/Hectare) |
|---:|:----------------------------|:-------------|:-------------------------|:---------|-----------------:|----------------------:|-------------------------:|
|  2 | Andaman and Nicobar Islands | Arecanut     | NICOBARS                 | Rabi     |           534.1  |                125.23 |                 0.234469 |
|  3 | Andaman and Nicobar Islands | Arecanut     | NORTH AND MIDDLE ANDAMAN | Rabi     |          1744    |               4639.44 |                 2.66023  |
|  4 | Andaman and Nicobar Islands | Arecanut     | SOUTH ANDAMANS           | Rabi     |          1220.2  |              10518.7  |                 8.62047  |
|  7 | Andaman and Nicobar Islands | Arhar/Tur    | NORTH AND MIDDLE ANDAMAN | Rabi     |             1.2  |                  0.6  |                 0.5      |
| 10 | Andaman and Nicobar Islands | Black pepper | NICOBARS                 | Rabi     |            12.4  |                  0.42 |                 0.033871 |
| 11 | Andaman and Nicobar Islands | Black pepper | NORTH AND MIDDLE ANDAMAN | Rabi     |             8.76 |                  2.13 |                 0.243151 |
| 12 | Andaman and Nicobar Islands | Black pepper | SOUTH ANDAMANS           | Rabi     |            69.46 |                349.72 |                 5.03484  |
```

Comment: This worked! However, I had to do some post-processing to make it the way look I wanted. It didn't take much time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full demo for how to do this... it's a little clunky, but I don't think there's a builtin pandas function to really achieve the explosion of "State/Crop/District" into respective columns. Besides the for loop it's not too bad :)

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """State/Crop/District             Season  Area (Hectare)  Production (Tonnes)  Yield (Tonnes/Hectare)
Andaman and Nicobar Islands  NaN             NaN     NaN                 NaN
Arecanut                    NaN             NaN     NaN                 NaN
1.NICOBARS                  Rabi            534.10  125.23              0.234469
2.NORTH AND MIDDLE ANDAMAN  Rabi            1744.00  4639.44             2.66023
3.SOUTH ANDAMANS            Rabi            1220.20  10518.7             8.62047
Arhar/Tur                   NaN             NaN     NaN                 NaN
1.NORTH AND MIDDLE ANDAMAN  Rabi            1.20    0.6                 0.5
Black pepper                NaN             NaN     NaN                 NaN
1.NICOBARS                  Rabi            12.40   0.42                0.033871
2.NORTH AND MIDDLE ANDAMAN  Rabi            8.76    2.13                0.243151
3.SOUTH ANDAMANS            Rabi            69.46   349.72              5.03484"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(data), sep="\s\s+")
l = list(zip(df.iloc[:, 0], df.iloc[:, 1]))
out = []
for i, (j, k) in enumerate(l):
    if str(k) == "nan":
        if str(l[i + 1][1]) == "nan":
            state = j
        else:
            crop = j
    else:
        district = j
    try:
        out.append([state.title(), crop.title(), district[2:].title()])
    except NameError:
        pass
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["State", "Crop", "District"], data=out)
df_final = pd.concat([df1, df.dropna().iloc[:, 1:]], 1).dropna()
```

Output (`print(df_final.to_string())`):

```
                          State          Crop                  District Season  Area (Hectare)  Production (Tonnes)  Yield (Tonnes/Hectare)
2   Andaman And Nicobar Islands      Arecanut                  Nicobars   Rabi          534.10               125.23                0.234469
3   Andaman And Nicobar Islands      Arecanut  North And Middle Andaman   Rabi         1744.00              4639.44                2.660230
4   Andaman And Nicobar Islands      Arecanut            South Andamans   Rabi         1220.20             10518.70                8.620470
6   Andaman And Nicobar Islands     Arhar/Tur  North And Middle Andaman   Rabi            1.20                 0.60                0.500000
8   Andaman And Nicobar Islands  Black Pepper                  Nicobars   Rabi           12.40                 0.42                0.033871
9   Andaman And Nicobar Islands  Black Pepper  North And Middle Andaman   Rabi            8.76                 2.13                0.243151
10  Andaman And Nicobar Islands  Black Pepper            South Andamans   Rabi           69.46               349.72                5.034840
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Here you are importing the `data` while writing it beforehand. If I want to use a CSV file, I have to use `read_csv()` But when I do that I get an error `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'title'`

Comment: Why don't you just use `read_excel` like you said in your question...?

Comment: Maybe it's misleading because I am overwriting the original dataframe... I'll change that

Comment: I am still getting this error `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'title'`

Comment: Try: `out.append([str(state).title(), str(crop).title(), str(district)[2:].title()])`

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Yes, I was thinking on similar lines.